# calling https://www.facebook.com from oracle utl_http with wildcard certificates

Tags: facebook, ssl, plsql, oracle12c

We are using oracle 12.1.0.1.0.

We have been issuing https calls through utl_http to a number of services with no problems.
We have been doing this for years and we have been using it for facebook authorization as well.

Lately, we are facing an issue with calling facebook.com urls in https that we cannot resolve.
It seems to have coincinded with the switch of facebook to using certificates on the *.facebook.com.
Though I hesitate to say that this is the cause, it may be related.
Just to save you time, we are good with network acl grants and have not certificate validation errors.

The error code we get it problem we get is:

```
    ORA-29273: HTTP request failed
    ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1130
    ORA-28750: unknown error
     ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1130
```

The error ocurs on the pl/sql line that issues the utl_http.begin_request.

**My question is: can anyone duplicate this problem?  Has anyone been there and found a solution? Any input is appreciated.**

I am including two examples: One is a call to the redhat.com domain which works fine.
The other is a call to the facebook.com domain that has the above issue.
The code used is the same in both cases.
Both domains use a certificate on the *.domain.

Target page: https://www.redhat.com/en/about

-- Certificate chain for the redhat page

```
    GTE CyberTrus Global Root
      Baltimore CyberTrust Root                 <===  rh_01.crt
        Cybertrust Public SureServer SV CA      <===  rh_02.crt
          *.redhat.com
```

-- The wallet contains the certificates marked by the arrow. We do not include the *.redhat.com certificate as only trusted certificates are supposed to go into the wallet.

-- Here is how the wallet for redhat.com was created.

```
    orapki wallet create -wallet /dir1/rh -pwd walletpassword -auto_login
    orapki wallet add    -wallet /dir1/rh -trusted_cert -cert "/dir1/rh/rh_01.crt" -pwd walletpassword
    orapki wallet add    -wallet /dir1/rh -trusted_cert -cert "/dir1/rh/rh_02.crt" -pwd walletpassword
```

-- Here is the code that makes the https call.

```
    declare
    wrequest         utl_http.req;
    wwallet_location varchar2(400) := 'file:/dir1/rh';
    wwallet_password varchar2(400) := 'walletpassword';
    wurl             varchar2(400) := 'https://www.redhat.com/en/about';
    begin
    utl_http.set_wallet(wwallet_location, wwallet_password);
    wrequest := utl_http.begin_request(wurl, 'GET', utl_http.http_version_1_1);
    end;
```

-- This works fine

===============================================
Here is the same setup that fails to call the facebook page.

Target page:https://www.facebook.com/login/identify?ctx=recover

-- Certificate chain for the facebook page

```
    GTE CyberTrus Global Root
      Baltimore CyberTrust Root               <===  fc01_.crt
        Digicert High Assurance EV Root CA    <===  fc02_.crt
          Digicert High Assurance CA-3        <===  fc03_.crt
            *.facebook.com
```

-- The wallet contains the certificates marked by the arrow

-- Here is how the wallet for facebook was created.

```
    orapki wallet create -wallet /dir1/fc -pwd walletpassword -auto_login
    orapki wallet add    -wallet /dir1/fc -trusted_cert -cert "/dir1/fc/fc_01.crt" -pwd walletpassword
    orapki wallet add    -wallet /dir1/fc -trusted_cert -cert "/dir1/fc/fc_02.crt" -pwd walletpassword
    orapki wallet add    -wallet /dir1/fc -trusted_cert -cert "/dir1/fc/fc_03.crt" -pwd walletpassword
```

-- Here is the code that makes the https call.

```
    declare
    wrequest         utl_http.req;
    wwallet_location varchar2(400) := 'file:/dir1/fc';
    wwallet_password varchar2(400) := 'walletpassword';
    wurl             varchar2(400) := 'https://www.facebook.com/login/identify?ctx=recover';
    begin
    utl_http.set_wallet(wwallet_location, wwallet_password);
    wrequest := utl_http.begin_request(wurl, 'GET', utl_http.http_version_1_1);

    end;
```

-- This code give the error

```
    ORA-29273: HTTP request failed
    ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1130
    ORA-28750: unknown error
     ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1130
```

Can you duplicate this error? Or is it just me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with some other service...

Comment: I had the some problem with the 11.1.0.7 but was working with the 11.2.0.4. You have even newer version of the DB so quite strange why it's not working. Oracle have patch for this to older DB versions but not maybe related to your problem: Patch 12927177: UTL_HTTP FAILS WITH ORA-28750: UNKNOWN ERROR ON SSL ACCESS

Comment: Have you tried hitting the URL using wget and curl from your database server's shell? We had a similar sounding problem (also not resolved) but we at least proved that the problem existed at the OS layer and not actually within Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

We are having same issue, and oracle confirmed they don't support wildcar SSL.